# Is there any iPAD simulator for WINDOWS in order to test using our ipa file?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios-simulator

How to test our .ipa file in windows machine? Is there any iPAD simulator for windows.. Is there any means that we can test our app in a windows machine?

Comment: there is no way . . .

Comment: Are you guys on the receiving end of a binary build of an app? Why not get the developers to setup a TestFlight account and have a more organized way of managing builds?

Comment: You wouldn't even be able to do it on the Mac simulator.  The IPA file is compiled for armv7/s processors, not i386.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the iOS SDK is only available for OS X.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's not. The compiler and Xcode are both entirely Mac-specific. There's also no iPad simulator available for windows. If you must write on a windows machine and you're in the game industry, however, you might look into writing your app with [Corona](http://www.coronalabs.com/products/corona-sdk/) or [Unity](http://unity3d.com). Otherwise, you're out of options.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible right on Windows as there's no IDE/Sim that runs on Windows for Mac/iOS apps. But if you're among the brave, daring kind you can technically run OS X as a virtual machine inside Windows or go one step ahead and try to install the retail OS on the Win hardware. Google around and figure it out yourself. Workarounds like these fall out of Stackoverflow's scope.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a way.  [This service](http://www.macincloud.com) provides a MAC in the cloud and lets you use both XCode and iOS simulator.